# Is there any way to render Excel files in MVC4 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, viewer

i have a problem, i need to show a group of excel files in some views of an mvc4 project. The real problem is that the files are Excel PowerPivot and they can not be shown as images or pdf, it has to be Excel files.
Any ideas?
Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the workbook in the Browser-based version of excel and see what you need to display, you can then use the Share->Embed feature of the Excel online app to generate HTML or JavaScript embed code.

If you need to have the end user manipulate the workbook to retrieve the necessary data from the PowerPivot table, then they'd most likely be better off downloading the workbook and going from that.

If they don't need to manipulate anything, look into if you can export the workbook to HTML in some fashion and embed that.

Hopefully that might put you down the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i´m going to try that,